# Is CMU Sphinx available via Maven?

Tags: java, maven, cmusphinx

I have an idea for an app that may need CMU Sphinx, is it available via maven, or do I need to add it by hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: CMUSphinx is going to be available in sonatype in a week or so. The maven support has already been committed into sphinx4 trunk.

Answer (score 4):

You can check from http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4:

Overview

Sphinx-4 is a pure Java speech recognition library. It's very flexible in its configuration, and in order to carry out speech recognition jobs quite a lot of objects depending on each other should be instantiated, throughout this article we will call them all together “object graph”. Fortunately, the most of the objects can be instantiated automatically, and for those few requiring manual setup Sphinx-4 provides high-level interfaces and a context class that takes out the need to setup each parameter of the object graph separately.

Using in your projects

Sphinx-4 is available as a maven package in Sonatype OSS repository. To use sphinx4 in your maven project specify this repository in your pom.xml:

```
<project>
...
   <repositories>
       <repository
           <id>snapshots-repo</id>
           <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
           <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
...
</project>
```

Then add sphinx4-core to the project dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.cmu.sphinx</groupId>
 <artifactId>sphinx4-core</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Add sphinx4-data to dependencies as well if you want to use default acoustic and language models:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.cmu.sphinx</groupId>
  <artifactId>sphinx4-data</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, the maven sections needed updating though, and sent you a revised edit, please post it.  Didn't want to re-post it in full with the fixes.